# Shell script: Why can't the if statement make a logical comparison?

Tags: shell, if-statement

I'm new to Unix and Linux in general and failed to make a logical comparison within an if statement.

I'm sure this is a very basic mistake but I just can't find the error.

```
if (7+3 == 10); then
    echo "nice this works"
elif (7+3 == 73); then
    echo "too bad string concatenation"
else
    echo "I really don't understand shell"
fi
```

Echo: I really don't understand shell.

Comment: I would expect you to see this error message twice: `7+3: command not found` -- did you?

Comment: Just 7+3: not found, but i have no idea what that means

Comment: That's the kind of detail that you need to put in your question. What are you trying to do? What do you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: Okey, I will remember this for the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect you to see this error message twice: `7+3: command not found` -- did you?

Single sets of parentheses run the enclosed commands in a subshell, so you're attempting to execute the command `7+3` with two arguments, `==` and `10` (or `73`)

Arithmetic evaluation occurs within **double** parentheses

```
if ((7+3 == 10)); then
     echo "nice this works"
elif ((7+3 == 73)); then
     echo "to bad string concatenation"
else
     echo "I really don't understand shell"
fi
```

```
nice this works
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then: using double parentheses ((7+3==10)) would be the same as using square brackets [7+3==10].

Comment: No. Square brackets are not just syntax. `[` is actually a **command**. At a bash shell prompt, type `help [` and then `help test` to see what arguments `[` can take. That command can do comparisons on two integers. It does **not** evaluate arithmetic expressions. `7+3` is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The operator your are using == is used for string comparisons. The right way to do it would be with the -eq (equal) operator:

```
if [ 10 -eq 10 ]; then
    echo "10 = 10"
fi
```

and you also need to use the right parenthesis for the if [ ] (you can look this up in the bash with 'man test')

Comment: Rahul also included the right way to add two integers with the shell

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be

```
if [ $((7+3)) -eq 10 ]; then
    echo "nice this works"
```